# Key phrase extraction tool in .net

Tags: .net, key, nlp, phrase

I am looking for a key phrase ( usually more than one words) extraction tool/library that can be used in .net. KEA , MAUI and other tools that i have search so far are in java.

Comment: I was really hoping you would get an answer.  I have been looking for a tool like this for over 2 years.  Tried writing one myself but discovered how difficult it is.

Comment: @Blam There are several tools in java. but havn't find anything in .net yet. Lets see.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to applications that need high amount of research the answers will be limited, so take the best answer that you find and expand your environment to accept it, in another words i suggest if you think that KEA is the app that you need, run your KEA application with java and "bridge" it to whatever environment you're using

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. Finally i wrote my own multi word extraction implementation using lucene.net. In my implementation i used ShingleFIlter and a custom built tokenizer to cross check the mwu to run against a flat file list and filter out unnecessary pairs. 
http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d7/deb/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_shingle_1_1_shingle_filter.html